# How to make toeplitz matrix constraint in cvxpy?

Tags: python, optimization, cvxpy, toeplitz

Using cvxpy( convex optimisation solver in python), there are options to make a matrix variable to be symmetric or positive semidefinite, but I require that the matrix be toeplitz (all left to right diagonals have the same element is each diagonal entry). Is there an efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Take a look at the first few lines of [this](https://mathoverflow.net/a/295232/91764)

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to add the constraint:

```
a[i,j] = a[i-1,j-1]
```

for all i,j>0. The presolver (part of a solver) would exploit this and reduce the size of the model.